# How to detect if the jpg jpeg image file is corrupted(incomplete)?

Tags: image, image-processing, web, jpeg

I have to show some images from others' image server on my website but some of the images from the image server can only partially show like below image
[image]

The image included width and height info but only show very top part of image. If I open the image with Chrome v61, it looks like below image
[image]

Chrome v61 shows this color to present the transparency in png image file but what does it mean in jpg jpeg image file?

Is there anyone knows how to detect this kind of corrupted(incomplete) image? I'm trying to aviod this kind of images showing on my website.

Comment: _"some of the images from the image server can only partially show"_ Can you provide **file link** of such image so we can check its bytes?

Comment: the file would be the same as the one I uploaded to the question.https://i.stack.imgur.com/dge40.jpg

Comment: When you upload to such sites, those images are more like "snapshots" of the problem. I need **original problem file** (to check for any **bad bytes**). If I simply check the `i.stack.imgur` image, all that data will tell me is just that this Jpeg photo has a lot of grey and white squares (possibly made with image editing tool like Photoshop). I'm trying to see if full image is recoverable from **exact data** sent by server.

Comment: Use a file share site like [**Google Drive**](https://www.google.com/drive/) (if you have Gmail to login, you can upload a shared file), also can use free [**Dropbox**](https://www.dropbox.com) or finally just email one to: _valerio_charles@yahoo.com_

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought imgur would show my original image. Here are 2 different corrupted jpg images. I also sent these files to your email. Thanks bro.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_UTda5aGfd1c1dlS1hVMmQwV0k/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_UTda5aGfd1MTZKU1A4VGR5bUk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you need a "programmatic" approach rather than the command line approach suggested by @MarkSetchell, you could create a very quick test for this in pretty much any programming language. *Note that this will only find the kind of truncating corruption you mention in your question.* Mark's method may be more reliable for finding corruption in general.

As we know, any JPEG file or stream is written according to the [JPEG Interchange Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_Interchange_Format). That means that they must start with a SOI (Start-of-Image) marker (the two bytes `0xFF, 0xD8`) and end with the EOI (End-of-Image) marker (two bytes, `0xFF, 0xD9`). These two markers will not be found anywhere else in a JPEG file/stream.

If you first identify the file as a JPEG by inspecting the first two bytes and matching against the SOI marker, you could skip to the end and search backwards for the EOI marker. Most likely, this will either be the last two bytes or you will not find them at all. But it may be safer to do a search (perhaps for a limited length), as I think it may be allowed to place application-specific data in a JPEG file after the EOI (someone, please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Thanks mate.Is there any way I can identify the corrupted jpg on browser JavaScript ?

Comment: @JasonHsieh Sure, if you can access the *compressed* image data, just do what I outlined above. If you need help writing that code, I'm not the one. Ask a new question specific for the task, and make sure you include what you have tried so far.

Comment: The JPEG stream is over once the EOI marker is reached. In theory data can go afterwards but it is unpredictable how an encoder might stream the stream.

Answer (score 30):

I created a JPEG to test this using **ImageMagick** as follows:

```
convert -size 1024x768 gradient: image.jpg
```

and it was 14kB. Your image looks like it is incomplete, so I chopped off everything after 3kB like this:

```
dd if=image.jpg bs=3000 count=1 > corrupt.jpg
```

Now, if I run **ImageMagick**'s `identify` command and discard `stdout`, just retaining `stderr`, I get:

```
identify -verbose corrupt.jpg > /dev/null
```

**Sample Output**

```
identify: Premature end of JPEG file `corrupt.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/364.
identify: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment `corrupt.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/364.
```

Alternatively, you could discard `stderr` too and simply look at the exit code (0=success, anything else=error):

```
identify -regard-warnings -verbose corrupt.jpg > /dev/null 2>&1
echo $?
1
```

whereas for a complete image:

```
identify -regard-warnings -verbose image.jpg > /dev/null 2>&1
echo $?
0
```

**ImageMagick** is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS/OSX and Windows.

Comment: With `find . | xargs -I % sh -c 'identify -regard-warnings -verbose % > /dev/null 2>&1;echo % $?'` you get the list of filenames as the first column and the result as a second column

Comment: A small modification to @schoetbi answer allows you to move the corrupt files out of a directory


    `find . | xargs -I % sh -c 'identify -verbose % > /dev/null 2>&1; if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then mv % ../unique-organized-corrupt; fi '`