# Partial image download using cURL. How to detect?

Tags: php, image, curl, imagick

We use PHP-cURL to download images from the web for one of our apps and sometimes the image downloads partially due to a timeout. Here is what a partially downloaded image looks like
[image]

I am wondering if there is any way to detect this using PHP? We don't see any errors as far as cURL is concerned.

Any imagick commands for example that can be used?

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/46805566/2836621

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if the jpg jpeg image file is corrupted(incomplete)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802866/how-to-detect-if-the-jpg-jpeg-image-file-is-corruptedincomplete)

Answer (score -1):

I realise this is an old post, but I stumbled upon it when I had the same issue.

I wrote this `php` code to check if the image file is valid:

```
function imageIsValid($local_path)
{
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($local_path);
    $valid = !!$im;
    imagedestroy($im);
    return $valid;
}
```

This works because `imagecreatefromjpeg` will return nothing if the image stream is corrupted.