# images (png, jpg or jpeg) is detected as corrupt with python's PIL / Pillow verify()

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am trying to detect corrupted images from a large dataset of images. I am using the Pillow package and verify(). 
I simply want to detect images that are corrupted or wont open with an image viewer or browser as "Bad flies" instead, ALL my images are always detected as "bad"

- I read in a git issue comment that pillow only detects png files, even with that, all my png images are detected as bad.
- I have also tested the code with randomly downloaded images online and its all getting detected as "bad files"
- note: I am coding in notebook++ (that shouldn't be a problem, right?)

```py
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image

for imageFolder in listdir('./batch1'):
    try:
        img = Image.open('./batch1'+imageFolder)
        img.verify()     # to veify if its an img
        img.close()     #to close img and free memory space
    except (IOError, SyntaxError) as e:
        print('Bad file:', imageFolder)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there any other method to achieve my goal of detecting corrupted images without deleting each corrupted image manually?

Comment: You need to think a bit more about what's a file and what's a directory and how you join the two. Try forming the full name of the file first and then using `img=Image.open(fullname)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell oooh ...... thanks ;)

Comment: You can detection truncation quite easily... a JPEG must have `EOI` (\xff \xd9) as its last 2 bytes https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format and a PNG must have `IEND` chunk at the end...https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics

Comment: Thanks again @Mark ..... I looked at the tagged links, I get that .... but I am in search of libraries (in python most preferably) or methods to detect corrupt images automatically using code

Comment: **ImageMagick** can detect such errors... https://stackoverflow.com/a/46805566/2836621 so I assume **Python Wand** can, so maybe @emcconville can assist

Comment: @MarkSetchell ..... great! thank you!.... I would check out Python Wand in the ImageMagick application  today.....although I am eager to write code to do that instead of using an application ...... again, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `/` after your path. Else your fullpath would seem something like `.'batch1your_img.png`

```
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image

for imageFolder in listdir('./batch1'):
    try:
        img = Image.open('./batch1/'+imageFolder)
        img.verify()     # to veify if its an img
        img.close()     #to close img and free memory space
    except (IOError, SyntaxError) as e:
        print('Bad file:', imageFolder)
```

Also make sure that your `batch1` directory containes only images, else you'll get another error.

Comment: myGoodness! Thank you!!! ..... I totally didn't notice that. Thanks...... that resolves detecting all images as corrupt, however, I am still not able to detect images that are ACTUALLY corrupted (images with about 68bytes and an image viewer app cannot open) .... thanks again!